# How I can update the old value using SQl?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Update PollOptions
Set Votes =((Select Votes from PollOptions Where PK_OptionID=3)+1)
```

How I can write this using sql code I want increase the last value one step now it didn't run it gives me error.

Comment: your SQL will update all the rows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update PollOptions Set Votes = Votes+1  Where PK_OptionID=3
```

SQL in OP might update all the rows

Answer (score 0):

```
Update PollOptions Set Votes = Votes + 1 where PK_OptionID=3
```